# How do I get jQuery and Mootools on the same Contao page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, contao

I am working on a Contao site that is supposed to be upgraded from 2.11.6 to 3.5.40 because the provider will soon force a PHP upgrade from 5.6 to 7.3. The upgraded site should look and feel like the old site.

I have already done the Contao upgrade, and all pages look fine except the **home page**, which uses two extensions:

```
• MenuMatic 0.68.3 for the main navigation (all pages use this)
• FlexSlider 1.4.3 directly underneath the menu (only on the home page)
```

MenuMatic uses Mootools, FlexSlider uses jQuery. The two extensions don't seem to work together. If I enable only Mootools, the menu works (hovering over one of the top elements drops down the submenu); if I add the FlexSlider content element with jQuery, the slider works, but not the menu dropdown. I haven't found a slider with fade option that runs with Mootools on contao 3.5.

MenuMatic injects these scripts on the page:

```
<!-- Load the MenuMatic Class -->
<script src="js/MenuMatic_0.68.3.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- Create a MenuMatic Instance -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var myMenu = new MenuMatic();
    });
</script>
```

This is what I tried:

```
• use a pure CSS menu: works on a simple html page, not on the Contao home page – no dropdown
• insert jQuery.noConflict() in the FlexSlider inline script
• wrap flexslider.js with jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { ... });
```

FlexSlider inline script with noConflict:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#schule").flexslider({
        slideshowSpeed: 6000,
        animationSpeed: 3000,
            animation: "fade",
        direction: "horizontal",
                    controlNav: false,
                    directionNav: false,
            randomize: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
                pauseOnAction: true,
        useCSS: false,
            touch: true
        });
    });
    })(jQuery);
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Can you help?

See my answer below.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to isolate the MenuMatic scripts? There's 4 of them all told.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't see that in the backend. Does 3.5 have a console, or is that only on the Symfony versions? Or do you mean another console?

Comment: There's nothing in the error log.

Comment: The browser (Firefox)  console has an error: TypeError: $ is not a function in   MenuMatic_0.68.3.js. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your MenuMatic script with https://gist.github.com/DimitarChristoff/7354353 for example.

Comment: Thanks @fritzmg! I found that before returning to this page. I googled "menumatic_0.68.3.js mootools version" and found the relevant SO question with the two parts I needed. Still +1 for you. Feel free to accept my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in two places:

1) https://gist.github.com/DimitarChristoff/7354353

Change js/Menumatic_0.68.3.js

from

```
var MenuMatic = new Class( {...} );
var MenuMaticSubMenu = new Class( {...} );
```

to

```
var MenuMatic;
var MenuMaticSubMenu;
(function ($) {
    MenuMatic = new Class( {...} );
    MenuMaticSubMenu = new Class( {...} );
}(document.id));
```

2) [jQuery/Mootools Conflict - Cant't find solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835780/jquery-mootools-conflict-cantt-find-solution)

Change assets/jquery/core/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

add `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end.

The noConflict in the FlexSlider script was not needed.

Another setting is needed though. In the page layout the jQuery and Mootools source should be set to `CDN with local fallback`. Don't really know why.

Menu and Slider work together!

Comment: You should not need to edit anything within `assets/`. As long as all your scripts are correctly wrapped, no `jQuerynoConflict()` call is necessary.

Comment: Well it didn't work without that. I've been working on this off and on for two weeks. No one had a solution for these abandoned frameworks. I might look at solving this in a clean way later, but for now I'm satisfied -- the deadline for the PHP switch is in 3 days.